# Get the imageview bounds after constraints resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, constraints

i have 4 images which in a tableViewCell. I have added constraints to each imageView so they dynamically will resize according to screen size the problem is i need the bounds of the size, but when i log the bounds it will always log the storyboard bounds of the images. Is there a way to get the bounds according to the applied constraints?

```
println(cell.image1.bounds)
```

Here is a illustration what i need it for. I've created a method which give a dashed border, but this is according to the bounds of the imageView, so this gives the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in `layoutSubviews()` after the call to `super.layoutSubviews()`. At this point, the image view's `frame` should be updated.

Comment: UITableViewController does not have a member named layOutSubviews

Comment: If you're not modifying the frame in your cell subclass, you can use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.